# Access outer angular component scoped element in inner scopes

Tags: angularjs

I have created 4 angular components. My code structure is as followed.

```
<user-container>
    <normal-user>
             ...
    </normal-user>
    <admin-user>
             ...
         <super-user>
                ...
         </super-user>
    <admin-user>
<user-container>
```

For each of the above tag separate component is created. Now I want to manipulate the DOM elements of `super-user` component on the basis of the variable of `user-container` component scope. so my question how can I access variable scoped in `user-container` component into `super-user` component?

Comment: Without seeing how your bindings are set up one simple way would be using a watch and an angular  event broadcast

Comment: sir first of all thanks you for the suggestion, could please explain me briefly in answers section or tag some relevant link.

Comment: Just trying to understand so your goal is to pass a variable availed on user-container component down to super-user component?

Comment: Nope. Inside the templateUrl page of super-user.

Answer (score 0):

So let’s say on your user-container component you have the variable

```
myVariable: boolean;
```

And now on your super-user component you have an input binding like this

```
@Input() myUserVariable: boolean;
```

Then on your template you simply do

```
<super-user [myUserVariable]=“myVariable”></super-user>
```

Where myVariable corresponds to the variable you defined on the outer container component user-container.

Of course this is the simplest case you can have more tricky scenarios but I believe this answers your base question. You simply set a bindable input property on the child component and then set it to which variable you want from the parent component ( public variables of course )

Comment: @Input() ? I am not using angular 2, it's angularJS

Comment: You tagged the question as angular. If it’s for angularjs it’s the wrong tag.